# Running RubyGem CLI during development

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am starting a new project which will have the need for a CLI.

I have created a new RubyGem project using

`bundle gem roar`

So I have structure in place.

To have the CLI I have created a 'bin' folder and added a 'roar' file with the following contents.

```
require 'roar'

test = Test::Talk.new
test.say_hello
```

I now want to run the 'roar' bin file that I have created, but if I run the following

```
ruby bin/roar
```

I get an error stating that ruby cannot find the gem 'roar'.  I am assuming that this is because I am not in the 'environment' so it does not know how to find my library.  So how can I run this so that I can execute the scripts I am writing?

I have a feeling that I can create a helper script for use with IRB, but I cannot work out how to do it.  Any suggestions are gratefully received.

(I am not attempting to circumvent the need for tests, I am trying to get my head around the CLI and I do not want to have to go through the install gem and execute cycle).

Thanks very much,

Russell

UPDATE:

As requested, the layout of my project looks like:

```
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── bin
│   └── roar
├── lib
│   ├── roar
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── roar.rb
├── roar.gemspec
├── spec
│   ├── roar_spec.rb
│   └── spec_helper.rb
└── tmp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally when you run an executable from a gem Rubygems will set up the `LOAD_PATH` for you so that it contains your gems’ lib directory. Obviously when you run the script in development Rubygems doesn’t get the chance to set things up for you so you will need to do it yourself.

One way to do this is in the script file itself. For example the [Haml](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/4.0.5/bin/haml#L4) and [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/blob/v3.1.2/bin/redcarpet#L21-22) gems do this. Somewhere near the top of your executable you would have something like this:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../lib'
```

(assuming a fairly typical directory layout).

Another way, if you want to avoid manipulating the load path in code, would be to add the lib dir in the command line. The `-I` option to the `ruby` command lets you do this, so you could run:

```
$ ruby -Ilib/ bin/roar
```

from the top level of your gem.

Alternatively you could use the `RUBYLIB` environment variable:

```
$ RUBYLIB=lib ruby bin/roar
```

or even (if `bin/roar` has a shebang line and is executable):

```
$ RUBYLIB=lib ./bin/roar
```

You could even export `RUBYLIB` so you didn’t need to specify it each time, but you would need to be careful about leaving it set if you did that.

Comment: Matt, thanks lots, this is what I wanted to do. Perfect

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your dir tree to clarify some things? I'm curious what your lib looks like.

But if you're trying to use your own gem, the simplest answer is that you need to gem install within the directory that you're making it in.  It was probably breaking because you couldn't require your own gem that hadn't been installed.  Try running `gem install roar` in your command line in the top level of roar/.  Once you've run `gem install roar` simply call `roar`.  The annoying part is that if it breaks somewhere else you will have to reinstall the gem every time you change something to test it.

Here's the github page for a simple gem I just made that might help you see the correct layout in action, https://github.com/TSiege/nytimes-top-story-gem.  It's readme might help clarify how to use a gem you make yourself.

Comment: I have added the tree of the layout of my Gem file as requested.  As I have commented to @ice, I was hoping there was a way I would be able to test my CLI commands without having to use 'gem install' before I could try it - it feels awkward.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently developing a gem I would suggest utilizing bundler's :path option in the Gemfile and point to your unpacked library. This will allow you to work on the Gem while running your scripts.

I would suggest pointing the path directly to your local unpacked rubygem library. Then running bundle install to ensure it's pointing to the correct path. Also, you will need to reload any running processes to grab changes from the unpacked gem library.

recommended via bundler.io:

`gem 'roar', :path => './vendor/extracted_library'`

Comment: thanks for this.  Does this mean that I have to install my gem before I am able to run any of the commands that I create in it?  I am trying to run the CLI commands that are in the Gem I am developing.

Comment: In reading your updates, it looks like I misunderstood a part of your question. If you're still in the gem library and trying to test out your rubygem's functionality. You can do this a few ways on the command line.

<code>
% gem build roar.gemspec
Successfully built RubyGem
Name: roar
Version: 0.0.0
File: roar-0.0.0.gem

% gem install ./roar-0.0.0.gem

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in not explaining properly.  I am writing a Gem that will contain script files in 'bin' and I want to run those files from with the gem whilst I am developing it.

Comment: You can do this a few ways on the command line.

<code>
`% gem build roar.gemspec
Successfully built RubyGem
Name: roar
Version: 0.0.0
File: roar-0.0.0.gem

% gem install ./roar-0.0.0.gem

% irb
>> require 'roar'
=> true`
</code>

This will allow you to then work with your rubygem on the command line to get a feel for how everything is working out.

If you are working on a project that uses this gem and the gem that's when I would use :path.

Comment: I wanted to add a final note that you could also use 

`bundle console`

from within your gem project and it will start up a ruby console with the current state of your gem code.